# What is the correct way to deal with similar but independent features?

Tags: agile, gitflow

Let's say we have a feature request come in and we begin work on it, which we'll call *feature-1*. It introduces some new logic to the application, which we'll call *logic-A* and *logic-B*. A programmer branches from the release branch and begins work on the feature.

Soon after, we get another feature request, which we'll call *feature-2*. It will implement *logic-A* and *logic-C* into the application. The *logic A* being implemented by this feature is the same *logic-A* as was implemented in *feature-1*.

Let's also say that given *logic-B*, *logic-A* might be implemented slightly differently than it would have been given *logic-C*, and also differently given both *logic-B* and *logic-C* (eg. with only one feature, the code would be less flexible than with both).

How should this situation be handled?

**Concrete Example** (to help with any confusion in my wording)

- *feature-1* is a feed from programmers.stackexchange.com.
- *feature-2* is a feed from gaming.stackexchange.com.
- *logic-A* is the implementation of a feed at all (assuming the application currently has no feeds), which links to the content as well and gives related information.
- *logic-B* is that the feed's source is from programmers.stackexchange.com.

  - Adds to *logic-A* that the related programming language is displayed.
- *logic-C* is that the feed's source is from gaming.stackexchange.com.

  - Adds to *logic-A* that the related game's name and box art is displayed.

Comment: I don't quite understand where exactly the problem lies: is it about merging *feature-1* and *feature-2* into the release branch, or about developing *logic-a* in the first place? If the *logic-a* in both feature branches is slightly different, why did you give it the same name? Perhaps a few ASCII-art diagrams showing the branches and commits would clear up my confusion (I tried drawing them up, but your question didn't provide an unambiguous description of exact repository state).

Comment: The idea is that *feature-1* was started before *feature-2* and has already had progress prior to the start of *feature-2*. We ideally don't want to duplicate the efforts of re-implementing *logic-A* twice or deal with the hassle of attempting to merge (and/or refactor) the two implementations later on. I added an example to the question to show how *logic-A* can be different (but not wildly different) in each feature.

Answer (score 1):

Situations aren't always perfectly predictable, and being able to quickly adapt to changes is what this agile stuff is all about.  You want to release value for your customer as soon as possible, but that doesn't mean you need to paint yourself into a corner by creating code you know will require a redesign almost immediately.

If I were the *feature-2* developer in your example, upon receiving the assignment and learning someone else was already working on something similar, I would:

- Go talk to the *feature-1* developer and agree on a branch where we can work on the common logic together.  This might be the branch he already created, or a separate one just for the common logic, whichever feels easier under the circumstances.
- Determine what changes we need to make to the current design of the common logic in order to accommodate both features.
- Determine the impact of those changes on the release date of *feature-1*.
- If it's a minimal impact to *feature-1*, I would just make the common logic changes in our shared branch and move forward.
- If it's a significant impact to *feature-1*, I would make the common logic changes in another branch, and merge it in after *feature-1* is finished.  The other developer will be able to help you with this.
- Another option if it's a significant impact to *feature-1* is that sometimes you can make a low-impact temporary change now to make the high-impact change easier down the road.  Don't make an all-or-nothing mistake.  For example, if you isolate the display of the "extra" data like the programming language into its own function, it will be easier to make that configurable later.

Answer (score 0):

This is more a project management question then a git question.

Best is to create 2 [INVEST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INVEST_(mnemonic)) stories:

1. Implements the generic logic needed for implementing feeds(logic-A). And implements the logic for whatever feed has the most value. So either logic-B or C
2. Implements the feed that hasn't been implemented using the generic logic in story 1. So either logic B or C

Then you plan story 1 in a sprint/release before you plan story 2. Work on story 2 can't begin until story 1 is finished so you should plan it in a release after story 1 is delivered. Story 1 is a dependency of story 2. And as such if story 1 isn't finished for whatever reason it blocks Story 2.

So if story 1 doesn't make release 1 and it gets moved to release 2. You will be forced to move story 2 to release 3. And this wil continue until story 1 is actually finished.

The reason why you have to implement the common logic in the same story. Is because upon implementing you will run in edge-cases you didn't foresee while developing the common logic.

Just building common logic first without implementing it is not [INVEST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INVEST_(mnemonic)) because it does not add value. Working in this way increases the risk of [over-engineering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overengineering) and adding features [you aren't gonna need](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren't_gonna_need_it)

If they dependency is discovered while both features are in development. Best practice is to put 1 of those features on impeded and pause the development of that feature.

Comment: Let's assume that we didn't make the connection that they were going to have shared functionality, or the first story failed into the next sprint where the second story begins, or some other means of forcing an overlap. Do we treat the first story as a dependency? Do we pause the first story to build the common logic separately?

Comment: @Koviko updated my answer to go a bit more in-depth. And provided more arguments as to why the common logic and the first implementation have to be done in the same story

Answer (score 0):

I assume feature2 arrived before too much work had been done on feature1. Otherwise you need to finish feature1 first. But if you have the luxury of choosing...
Prioritize feature1 and feature2 based on how much value they add to the project. 
Add logicA in the way that benefits the feature you're adding first. It's ok to at least be aware that you will use logicA for another feature, but don't go nuts.
Finish the first feature, so logicA is earning the highest amount of value possible (because you prioritized the most valuable feature).
Refactor logicA as needed to implement the other feature.This earns the most value soonest.

After coding the first feature, you get a chance to decide if the cost of refactoring logicA is too high and not do the second feature unless it becomes more valuable. You know more about logicA. Maybe your fear that you couldn't reuse logicA is unfounded. You also have experience implementing logicA. So if you have to refactor or completely redesign logicA, you can do it from a standpoint of knowledge, rather than trying to design logicA for any conceivable use from a standpoint of no real knowledge of the use cases.